# How to get Facebook user's interests list

Tags: php, facebook

How I can get the interests of facebook user.

```
 $fql1    =   "SELECT * FROM table WHERE uid = me()";

 $param1  =   array(

 'method'    => 'fql.query',

 'query'     => $fql1,

 'callback'  => ''

 );
 $fqlResult1   =   $facebook->api($param1);
```

Can anyone edit my query

Answer (score 0):

FQL is deprecated and should not be used anymore.

You can get the liked pages with the /me/likes endpoint, for example code and information check out the Facebook docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/likes